# yii relation for multiple column foreign keys

Tags: php, mysql, database, yii

I have a table `Friend (PersonA, PersonB)`. These are foreign keys of `Person(id, name)`.

I want to create a Yii relation between them. This is what I have come up with:

```
public function relations() {
    return array(
        'friends1' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Friend', 'PersonA'),
        'friends2' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Friend', 'PersonB'),
    );
}
```

Is there a way to combine these two relations into one? I was hoping for something like this:

```
public function relations() {
    return array(
        'allFriends' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Friend', 'PersonA, PersonB'),
    );
}
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT #1:**

For completeness, let's also imagine that I want to order `friends1` and `friends2` like this:

```
public function relations() {
    return array(
        'friends1' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Friend', 'PersonA', 'order'=>'id ASC'),
        'friends2' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Friend', 'PersonB', 'order'=>'id ASC'),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me :

Override the `__get` function in your model:

```
public function __get($name)
{
    if(($name == 'friends1') || ($name == 'friends2')) {
        return parent::__get('friends1') + parent::__get('friends2');
    }
    else
        return parent::__get($name);
}
```

Comment: This is simple function override.

Comment: This would have been ok with ruby on rails maybe.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be ok with PHP Object Inheritance ? `class mymodel extends CActiveRecord { public function __get(...) { ... } }`

Comment: Because in yii the __get and __set methods are already overwritten, you don't have to do it

Comment: But it will still use the parent function overridden or not, you don't have to care about that... This is specific to the model. If you want to get a specific attribute, return both attributes. That's a really simple way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same thing come up in something I was working on. What I did is I created another function to compile the two relations into one array. The reason for this is because even if you were to get the two relationships combined, each time you would still need to test to see if PersonA or PersonB is the current user's id and use the other id to pull the Friends info. Here is the function I created in my model:

```
public function getFriends() {
    $all_friends = array();
    foreach($this->friends1 as $friend) {
        if($friend->PersonA == $this->id) {
            $all_friends[] = $friend->PersonA;
        } else {
            $all_friends[] = $friend->PersonB;
        }
    }
    foreach($this->friends2 as $friend) {
        if($friend->PersonA != $this->id) {
            $all_friends[] = $friend->PersonA;
        } else {
            $all_friends[] = $friend->PersonB;
        }
    }
    return $all_friends;
}
```

Another options:

```
public function getFriends() {
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->compare('PersonA',$this->id);

    $criteria2 = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria2->compare('PersonB',$this->id);

    $criteria->mergeWith($criteria2,'OR');

    $friends = Challenge::model()->findAll($criteria);
    return $friends;
}
```

Then for any Person you can just say:

```
$person = Person::model()->findByPk(1);
$friends = $person->friends;
```

Or instead of an array you could send back an `CActiveDataProvider` that you could do sorts and other things with. You could do this:

```
public function getFriends() {
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->compare('PersonA',$this->id);

    $criteria2 = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria2->compare('PersonB',$this->id);

    $criteria->mergeWith($criteria2,'OR');

    return new CActiveDataProvider('Friend', array(
        'criteria' => $criteria,
    ));
}
```

Then since you have CActiveDataProvider you can sort:

```
$friends = $user->friends->getData(); //not sorted or anything
//or you can manipulate the CActiveDataprovider
$data = $user->friends;
$data->setSort(array(
    'defaultOrder'=>'PersonA ASC',
));
$friends = $data->getData();
```

Comment: Ahh I see. :( This wouldn't utilise any of the neat SQL features like ORDER BY - I would have to programatically sort it myself - which is OK but a bit annoying as SQL would neatly do it all for me.

Comment: You could easily create it with CDBCriteria and CActiveDataProvider if you want to do that.

Comment: hmmm....I don't understand. As I can see it above, you will get one array returned from this method --- the first half will be where the person is noted down in `PersonA` followed by those in `PersonB`. No? Where would `CDBCriteria` and `CActiveDataProvider` come in?

Comment: It would be a different function, in your OP you were just getting an array of Friend instances which wouldn't be able to be sorted by name or anything either. So I was just mimicking what you had started.

Comment: Ok. :) I have updated my OP with the new relations - here I am ordering by ID in `friends1` and `friends2`. Are you saying you have a solution to include this ordering? Using `CDBCritera` and `CActiveDataProvider`? Or would I be limited to just standard programmatic sorting?