# hasMany with 'or' condition

Tags: activerecord, yii2

I have two tables: `users` with primary key `id`, and `friends` with foreign keys `user1` and `user2` both related to user's `id`.

In Users model I have

```
public function getFriends() {
    return $this->hasMany(Friends::className(), ['user1' => 'id'])->inverseOf('user');
}
```

`User::find()->with('friends')->all()` find only those friends, where user1 matches given user's id.

How should I change `getFriends()` to find friends with user1 **or user2** matched to user's id?

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding bidirectional relation

EDIT: following #1 solution is not working, despite yii dev advised it there

---

According to http://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/851 this should work

```
public function getFriends() {
    return $this->hasMany(Friends::className(), ['user1' => 'id'])
        ->viaTable('friends', array('user2' => 'id'), function ($q) {
            $q->where('user1=user2');
    });
}
```

---

EDIT:

Found some other solution, if you have not sorted it out yet, check this link [yii relation for multiple column foreign keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516985/yii-relation-for-multiple-column-foreign-keys)

Comment: It generates the following queries: `SELECT * FROM friends WHERE (user1=user2) AND (user2=123)` and `SELECT * FROM friends WHERE 0=1` (123 is user's id)

Comment: oh yeah, it seemed bit weird to me, did you find solution yet ?